# how to find a symbol file and tell crash about it

Tags: linux-kernel, crash, gdb, crash-dumps

I am debugging in issue in the Linux kernel using the crash utility to inspect a kernel crash core. But when I try to inspect contents of a particular instance of struct r5conf, crash tells me it does not know that struct or its layout.

```
crash> struct r5conf
struct: invalid data structure reference: r5conf
```

So, how do I tell crash about the layout of this structure?

Comment: Perhaps, this symbol is in an external module, not in the kernel itself? If that so, then you need to add that module's debug data: `mod -s <module name>` (please run help for the `mod` command if it doesn't work that way). Would that be the `md` module in your case? After that you should be able to show the contents of the structure.

Comment: I will try that...makes sense.

Comment: that worked. thanks.